# how to add multple color to same polyline in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I am building ECG app. in this I have to use different colours for same polyline in portion. I have tried to search it lot but i cant get anything on that. Please someone help me.

Comment: What is it **exactly** that you want to achieve? If different segments need to have different colours then you'll need to have separate polylines.

Comment: i think your approach towards answer is quite right. can you explain it through code sample.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can just use a gradient as the colour, instead of a solid colour. This will give the illusion of various colours on the same polyline.